# QuotaExceededError: Failed to OpenBackingStore on iOS

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, quota, angular-service-worker

We have a more or less big Web-Application. It builds up on Angular and PWA via the Angular tools are activated.
It works all very well and the offline mode also works as it should.

The application has a big library that is cached (as we are using PDFTron-Webviewer). The PDFTron-Webviewer must be available in Offline-Mode, so it is cached by the Service-Worker.

Every time after a view updates (especially when we deliver a new Version of the WebViewer-Library), the following error(s) occur: Error: Uncaught (in promise): `QuotaExceededError: Failed to OpenBackingStore in database because not enough space for domain`.

Error Message from Safari Devtools
[image: Error Message from Safari Devtools]

In the Application there is also functionality to save files (PDFs/DOCs/...) offline for use in offline Mode. These files are stored in the IndexedDB.

But I have no idea how to get rid of this error. The current workaround is to delete the PWA from the device and reinstall it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For everyone who ran into a similar problem.

It seems like iOS is holding the old Versions of the PWA for a specific amount of time (and therefore fills up the available Space for PWAs). If do a lots of testing and have a bunch of "new" Versions in my test system i ran into this error.

In the production system on the other side i did not have this problem until now. Also turns out, that a restart of the iOS-Device often helps to solve the problem.